# Refreshing Navigation In VUEJS

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Assume that Home, Login and Register links in my navigation. After login, I want to hide or remove Login and Registration Links and instead want to display Logout and Dashboard Menu.

It works when I refresh the page. What is the best way to do that programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code you can refresh page with JavaScript:

```
// like an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("/");

// like clicking on a link
window.location.href = "/";
```

This will redirect to your home page. If you want you can replace / with any address you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [vue-router](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router) to specify components in each view or you can use **v-if** or **v-show** directives to programmatically change flags of code blocks.